# R: create data frame from data from other data frame

Tags: dataframe, copy-paste, data-wrangling

I try to create a new df(df1) by importing data from another df0. Let's say df0 has two variables v1 and v2 as below:

```
v1  v2
-1  0.1
0   0.2
1   0.3
-1  0.4
0   0.5
1   0.6
-1  0.7
0   0.8
1   0.9
-1  1
0   1.1
1   1.2
```

the v1 in df0 has a repeated value (here I simplified it as -1, 0, 1). I want to create a new df that copy v2 in df0 to each column based on the repeated value in v1. the new df should be like:

```
 x1 x2  x3  x4
0.1 0.4 0.7 1
0.2 0.5 0.8 1.1
0.3 0.6 0.9 1.2
```

what I have been done is:

```
# create a new df with NA
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 3)
df1[,] <- NA

# use for loop to copy data from df0 to df1

a <- seq(1,nrow(df0),3)
c <- as.numeric(1:4) 

for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  df1[,c[i]] <- df0[a[i]:a[i]+2, 2]  
}
```

It keeps creating errors like:

"replacement has x row, data has y"

or

"incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"

there must be a simple solution for this but I couldn't figure it out. It would be much appreciated if you could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out. the problem was caused due to the type of data. one was a numeric vector and the other was a matrix array.

df1[,c[i]] <- as.vector(df0[a[i]:a[i]+2, 2])  solved the problem.